# How to sort a string list according to equality to a string?

Tags: java, list, sorting, autofill

I have a big string list of names and an autofill function for a combobox.
Currently i'm just filtering according to contains. 
But the order in the combobox isn't nice.

Is there a easy way to sort the string list (after contains) according to equality to a string?

Example:

```
Currently:
combobox input -> Neustadt
List<String> 1. Bad Neustadt an der Saale
             2. Bremen-Neustadt
             3. ...
             n. Neustadt
           n+1. Neustadt / Pelzerhaken

Wandted:
1. Neustadt
2. Neustadt / Pelzerhaken
3. ...
n. Bremen-Neustadt
```

**EDIT**
Based on Petr Gladkikh's answer my solution is following method:

```
public static List<String> sortListCompairedToEquality(List<String> list, String str) {

  if (list == null || str == null)
    return null;

  final String compStr = str.toLowerCase();

  Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
      s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
      s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

      if (s1.equals(compStr) && !s2.equals(compStr)) {
        return -1;
      } else if (!s1.equals(compStr) && s2.equals(compStr)) {
        return 1;
      } else if (s1.indexOf(compStr) < s2.indexOf(compStr)) {
        return -1;
      } else if (s1.indexOf(compStr) > s2.indexOf(compStr)) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
  });

  return list;
}
```

Comment: you could implement `comparator` interface, and define how you want to compare in the `compare` method.

Comment: Use `Collection.sort(list)`

Comment: @NinadPingale - without a custom `Comparator` implementation, `Collections.sort()` won't help.. The strings will be sorted in *natural Order*.

Comment: please define the desired sorting order. In the next step your should write a custom comparartor for tis definition.

Comment: @TheLostMind - Yes but he has only Strings in the list and not objects , so I think natural order sorting is possible.

Comment: @NinadPingale - Sorting based on natural order is *always* possible (irrespective of Object type, the type should have implemented *Comparable*).. But is that what the OP wants?

Comment: @NinadPingale *No* he wants the strings sorted by distance to another string, not the strings in the list by their natural ordering. That is a huge difference.

Comment: Got it, sorry for my incorrect comment..

Comment: @TheLostMind: I didn't know the comparator before. I now solved my problem with the code snippet of Petr Gladkikh and added my solution in the post above.

Comment: @besnep - Yep.. That ought to work.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what rules of "equality to a string" you have in mind. Generally if you want to sort according to some rules use 'sort' method with custom comparator:

```
java.util.Collections.sort(listOfStrings, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return 0; // Your comparison logic goes here
        }
    });
```

See javadoc for java.util.Comparator interface for details.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the Comparator. But i got it to work exactly as i want it. I've added my solution on my post. Eventually you can understand what i wanted, by reading my code. ;) (sorry my english isn't good enough for explaining my need).